# Fill Excel + populate active x comobo box from Microsoft Sql Management Studio database table

Tags: database, vba, excel, combobox

I have an excel file I am trying to pull values in from a Microsoft SQL Database. I am trying to add values from a table using the table's ID and string value associated with that ID. I have run into an invalid argument error. I was able to add the xlVal if i declared the integer value and set the first item = 0, then i could add 1 to the xlVal to make each integer value unique but these values won't allow me to reference the specific row in the database if i want to pull the values back to update the database. Basically i am wondering if there is a way to set the pvargindex value = to my database ID value since i don't have an integer in my database starting with 0. I also tried adding a row (select type..., 0) before the loop ran but i was unable to get this to work either.

```
Private Sub populateType()
Dim dbName As Object
Dim dbResults As Object
Set dbName = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set dbName = openDBConn("./System", "System")
Set dbResults = dbName.Execute("SELECT ID_Type, Type FROM Const_Type WHERE Active = 1 AND Type <> 'N/A' ORDER BY Type")

Sheet1.ComboBox1.Clear

Do While Not dbResults.EOF

    Dim xlStr As String
    xlStr = dbResults("Type").Value
    Dim xlVal as integer 
    xlVal = dbResults("ID_Type").Value

    Sheet1.ComboBox1.AddItem xlStr, xlVal

    dbResults.MoveNext

Loop
```

End Sub